# Preimage of codimension one subvarieties under a dominant map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism of projective varieties over an algebraically closed field. If $Z\subset Y$ is a codimension $1$ subvariety, do the irreducible components of $f^{-1}(Z)$ necessarily have codimension $1$ in $X$?

I am asking about codimension $1$ since I know codimension $1$ usually behaves the best.

If this is true, is there an easy explanation? If this is almost true, what is the correction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer has been edited to discuss the general case.]

I will assume that *variety* means irreducible (otherwise you could work on individual irreducible components).  Then $f:X \to Y$ is dominant by assumption, and has closed image since its source is projective, thus it is surjective.
Thus $f^{-1}(Z) \to Z$ is also surjective.

Now, as described in e.g. [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193/when-is-fiber-dimension-upper-semi-continuous/202#202) (or in a Hartshorne exercise, maybe in Section 4 of Chapter II), for the proper map $f$, the function $y \mapsto \dim f^{-1}(y)$ is upper semicontinuous, so if $z \in Z$, then the dimensions of $f^{-1}(z)$ are at least $\dim X - \dim Y$.  This implies that $f^{-1}(Z)$ contains components of 
codimension $1$. (The intuition is just that we can add the dimension of $Z$ and of a typical fibre.  One way to make this precise is to note that if every component of $f^{-1}(Z)$ were of codimension at least $2$, then since it dominates $Z$, we would see that
a generic fibre would be of dimension $\dim X - \dim Y -1$, whereas we already noted that every fibre has dimension at least $\dim X - \dim Y$.)

---

In general you can't do better than this, because there are morphisms of $3$-folds (just to take an example) which are birational, but in which the preimage of some particular point $y \in Y$ is a curve.  Then if you take $Z$ to be a generic codim'n one subvariety passing through $y$, its preimage will be the union of a codim'n subvariety of $X$ (the *proper transform* of $Z$) and the curve $f^{-1}(P)$.   So in general you can't expect $f^{-1}(Z)$ to be equidimensional.

Note also that $f^{-1}(Z)$ can also contain multiple components of codimension $1$.  (E.g. let $X \to Y$ be the blow up of a surface at a point, and let $Z$ be a curve that passes through the blown up point.)

---

Rereading the question, I see that the point of the question might be the equidimensionality, and so you might be interested in the counterexample involving $3$-folds.  [This MO question and answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99075/crepant-resolutions-of-odps-on-a-3-fold) gives one such example.

Comment: Thanks, I was interested in equidimensionality, but knowing that some components have codimension 1 also helps.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I rewrote this answer with more details.

You need some more assumptions; the easiest one I know is to require that the dimension of the fiber $f^{-1}(\eta)$ of the generic point $\eta \in Y$ is equal to $\dim(X) - \dim(Y)$.

(1)  Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over a base scheme $S$.  Recall that if $X \to S$ is universally closed, then $f : X \to Y$ is also universally closed.  In fact we can factor $f$ through the closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow X \times_S Y$ and the projection $X \times_S Y \to Y$; closed immersions are proper, hence *a priori* universally closed, and the second is a base change of a universally closed morphism, hence also universally closed.  See [(Stacks, 01W6)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6).

(2)  Suppose the structural morphism $X \to S$ is universally closed.  Any $S$-morphism $f : X \to Y$ is closed by (1), and hence *surjective* if it is dominant.

(3)  The following proposition is from (EGA, IV_2, 5.6.6):

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible schemes, $Y$ locally noetherian, $f : X \to Y$ dominant and locally of finite type.  Let $e = \dim(f^{-1}(\eta))$ be the dimension of the generic fiber ($\eta \in Y$ being the generic point).  Then one has the inequality*

$$ \dim(X) \leq \dim(Y) + e. $$

*Further, if $Y$ is universally catenary then one has equality if and only if*

$$ \dim(Y) = \sup_{y \in f(X)} \dim(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}). $$

Note that this clearly holds when $f$ is surjective (EGA, IV_2, 5.1.4).

(4)  Let $S$ be a locally noetherian and universally catenary scheme, and let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes locally of finite type over $S$, with $X$ proper over $S$.  Let $Z \subset Y$ be a closed irreducible subscheme, let $(W_\alpha)$ be the irreducible components of the inverse image $f^{-1}(Z)$, and let $f_\alpha : W_\alpha \to Z$ denote the restrictions of $f$ to $W_\alpha$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ are locally of finite type over $S$, $W_\alpha$ and $Z$ are locally of finite type over $S$ and it follows that $f_\alpha : W_\alpha \to Z$ are locally of finite type [(Stacks, 01T8)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T8).  Also, $Z$ is universally catenary [(Stacks, 02J9)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02J9) and locally noetherian [(Stacks, 01T6)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T6).  Since $W_\alpha$ is proper over $S$, $f_\alpha$ is surjective by (2).  Hence by (3) one sees

$$ \dim(W_\alpha) = \dim(Z) + e, $$

where $e$ is the dimension of the fiber of the generic point $\eta \in Y$, and in particular the inverse image $f^{-1}(Z)$ is *purely* of dimension $\dim(Z) + e$.

(5)  If $X$ and $Y$ are further *biequidimensional* (EGA, 0_IV, 14.3.3), i.e. one has the formula

$$ \dim(W) + \mathrm{codim}(W, X) = \dim(X) $$

for every closed subspace $W \subset X$ (and likewise for $Y$), then one can rewrite (4) as

$$ \mathrm{codim}(f^{-1}(Z), X) = \mathrm{codim}(Z, Y) + m - n - e, $$

where $m$ and $n$ are the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

(6)  In particular, when $S = \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is the spectrum of a field $k$, then $X$ and $Y$ are biequidimensional (EGA, IV_2, 5.2.1) and the formula of (5) holds.  More generally, $S$ only needs to be Jacobson (and locally noetherian, universally catenary); this is not in EGA but I believe it's buried in some form in the Stacks project (see the comments on [(Stacks, 02S2)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02S2)).

(7)  Concluding, we have seen that in good cases, and in particular in your case, when the dimension of the generic fiber is equal to $\dim(X) - \dim(Y)$, the codimension of the inverse image $f^{-1}(Z)$ in $X$ is equal to the codimension of $Z$ in $Y$.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!