# The irreducible components of $f^{-1}(0),$ where $f \colon V \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is dominant, have codimension 1.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a question from Fulton's *Intersection Theory,* Example 1.5.1. Let $V$ be a variety of dimension $k+1$ and let $f \colon V \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a dominant morphism. Let $0 = (1:0)$ and $\infty = (0:1)$ be the zero and infinite points of $\mathbb{P}^1.$ Then Fulton states that the inverse image schemes $f^{-1}(0) = V \times_{\mathbb{P}^1} \{0\}$ and $f^{-1}(\infty) = V \times_{\mathbb{P}^1} \{\infty\}$ are purely $k$-dimensional subschemes of $V,$ but I'm having trouble seeing why this is true.

If $V$ were a projective variety, I believe this would follow from [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344210/preimage-of-codimension-one-subvarieties-under-a-dominant-map). However, I think the proof of the answers definitely relies on the fact that $V$ is projective, in order to say that the structure morphism of $V$ is proper, hence $f$ is also proper. But because our $V$ can be any variety, I'm assuming this proof will not work for us.

Could anybody give me some ideas to show why Fulton's statement is indeed true?

Comment: Are you sure his definition of "variety" without any adjectives doesn't assume projective or at least proper?

Comment: @TabesBridges He says a variety will be a reduced an irredicuble scheme, and a scheme is a scheme X over a field K, together with a morphism of finite type from $X$ to $\mathrm{Spec}(K).$ Then surely this definition is too loose for $V$ to be proper, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need proper here, just Krull's height theorem.

First, replace $0$ or $\infty$ in $\Bbb P^1$ by $0$ in $\Bbb A^1$ by taking the fiber product along either standard open immersion $\Bbb A^1\to\Bbb P^1$ so that we're considering the map $f':X\times_{\Bbb P^1}\Bbb A^1\to \Bbb A^1$ and looking at $f'^{-1}(0)$. Next, cover $X\times_{\Bbb P^1}\Bbb A^1$ by affine opens $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$. Let $f_i:k[x]\to A_i$ be the map of rings corresponding to $\operatorname{Spec} A_i\to \Bbb A^1$; this is an injective map of domains for each $i$ by the hypothesis that $f$ (and therefore $f'$) is dominant. By Krull's Principal Ideal theorem, any minimal prime of $A_i$ over $(f_i(x))$ is of height zero or one. Height zero is impossible, since the only prime ideal of height zero in a domain is $(0)$ and $f_i(x)$ cannot be nilpotent by hypothesis. Therefore every minimal prime over $(f_i(x))$ is height one, which means that every irreducible component of $f_i^{-1}(\{0\})$ is of codimension one, and therefore $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is of pure codimension one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a few questions though. I'm a bit unclear what purpose the fiber product of the two immersions is serving here. Isn't $0 \in \mathbb{P}^1$ naturally identified with $0 \in \mathbb{A}^1$ when we take the two standard affine opens covering $\mathbb{P}^1?$
Also, is there a map $f_i \colon \mathrm{Spec}(A_i) \to \mathbb{A}^1$ for all $i?$ Can't some affine open completely map to $\mathbb{P}^1 - \mathbb{A}^1?$

Comment: 1) I want to consider $X\times_{\Bbb P^1} \Bbb A^1$ instead of $X$ where $\Bbb A^1$ is either of the standard open immersions. This has everything which maps to whichever of $0$ or $\infty$ we're considering. 2) Yes, by construction - remember, we're replacing $X$ by the stuff in 1). And no open subset of a variety can map in to $\Bbb P^1\setminus\Bbb A^1$: this implies the map $X\to\Bbb P^1$ is not dominant.

Comment: When you say we're replacing $X$ by the stuff in (1), are the affine opens $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$ in your answer actually covers of $X \times_{\mathbb{P}^1}\mathbb{A}^1?$ Or are they still just covers of our original $X?$

Comment: I've edited the answer to try and be a little clearer - reading it with new eyes today I realize it could have been phrased better.

Comment: I'm sure my confusion had a lot more to do with my lack of knowledge than your phrasing, but thank you! I think that clears everything up for me.